# A SAT related question

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, polynomial-hierarchy

Given a sequence of $n$ propositional formulas $\varphi_1, \cdots, \varphi_n$, a propositional formula $\phi$, a number $1\leq \theta\leq n$.

Define $K=\min\{k\mid \wedge_{i=k}^n \varphi_i\not\models \phi\}$, i.e., it is the minimal number $k$ such that the conjunction of $\varphi_k, \cdots, \varphi_n$ does *not* imply $\phi$.

Question: what's the complexity of deciding whether $K=\theta$?

What I have tried: Since deciding $\wedge_{i=k}^n\varphi_i\not\models \phi$ is NP-complete, this problem is in $P^{NP}$. Moreover, by binary search, this can be improved to $\Theta^p_2$, i.e., only logarithmic number of NP queries is enough. (Is this correct?) However, I am not clear about the lower bound. Maybe it is just in NP?

Comment: You only need to test $\theta$ and $\theta+1$, so the problem is in DP. It’s not difficult to prove that it’s actually DP-complete.

Comment: I mean $\theta$ and $\theta-1$.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with DP, so could you please outline the DP-hardness?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Note that the intersection is pointwise. And you probably mean $\mathsf{BH}_2$.